# GL(V) is a group of invertible linear transformations and GL(V) contains of bijective and linear f?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory

In my textbook it says that

$GL=\{f: V \rightarrow V |\text{f is bijective and linear}\}$

But later in a result of a exercise it says that: 
"A representation is a group homomorphism $\varphi : G \rightarrow GL(V)$, where $GL(V)$ is the group of invertible linear transformations $T: V \rightarrow V$.

Can someone please explain me the "connect" between GL(V) is a group of invertible linear transformations and GL(V) contains of bijective and linear f?

Comment: invertible = bijective.  This is an elementary fact on functions between sets.

Comment: I noticed some specific formulations in some of your questions which made me curious: Does the course you are following happen to use my notes on representation theory?

Comment: yes it is :) We are trying to understand representation theory through your notes.

Comment: Cool. Is this at AU? Good to hear that they are still in use.

Comment: Yes it is :) For us who thinks representation theory is tough our lecturer referred to your notes. Do you maybe have hints, notes or answer sheet for the exercises in your notes which you can share?

Comment: Unfortunately, I never wrote up answers to the exercises, and I don't really have any further hints, other than asking here can be a good way to progress. What is used for the rep theory part as the main text?

Comment: okay :) Fulton Harris

Answer (score 1):

Let $V$ be a vector space on some field $\mathbb{K}$.

$\mathcal{L}(V)$, the set of endomorphisms of $V$, is a ring for the $+$ and $\circ$ laws, with identity $\textrm{id}_V$. So we can talk about the invertible elements of $\mathcal{L}(V)$: they are the linear transformations $u$ such that there exists some linear transformation $v$ such that $v \circ u = u \circ v = \textrm{id}_V$.

This definition enables us to say that the invertible elements of $\mathcal{L}(V)$ are the bijective linear applications from $V$ to $V$. Indeed, a basic theorem gives us that a bijective linear applications $u$ from $V$ to $V$ has its inverse that is also linear, so such an application $u$ is an invertible element of $\mathcal{L}(V)$. The reciprocal is obvious: an invertible element of $\mathcal{L}(V)$ is linear and bijective.